# What do git checkouts really mean?

Tags: git, git-checkout

What are `checkout`s in git?

I know once you do `checkout` to a particular branch, the `HEAD` points to that branch. But what does it really mean? Does it mean I can then work on that branch? If yes, then, without checking out a branch, I am not able to work on it?

Also, what does `remote checkout` mean? How is it useful?

Comment: None taken. Yes I have and I come across the theory of what it mean. i.e. point to HEAD etc. But I want to know from "checkout code - make changes - check in" point of view or is it different?

Comment: @antonijn -- I've tried googling the question -- this is the first result -- kind of sad that once I got here I saw the question was closed and this crazy attitude everyone has -- I come from TFS background, and I'm starting to suspect "Checkout" means something completely different in GIT.  I want to know what it *means* in git-land.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As you noted, `HEAD` is a label noting where you are in the commit tree.  It moves with you when you move from one commit to another.  `git checkout <commit>` is the basic mechanism for moving around in the commit tree, moving your focus (`HEAD`) to the specified commit.

The commit can be specified by any of a number of ways, commit hash, branch name, tag name, the relative syntax (`HEAD^`, `HEAD~1`, etc.) and so on.  It is often useful to consider a checkout to be changing branches, and there are some options that work from that perspective, but they all reference commits.

To checkout a commit has some side effects other than moving `HEAD` around.

- The working directory is updated to the state of the checked out commit.
- if a branch name is specified, checkout makes that branch active.  The active branch will move along with any new commits that are added.

  - with the `-b` option a new branch will be created based on the current commit and then made active.
  - with the `--track` option the checked out branch can be made aware of a remote branch
  - with the `--orphan` option a new branch is created (like with `-b`) but will not be based on any existing commit.

There are a few more options, which you can read about in the [git checkout man-page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), all of which revolve around moving from one commit to another -- just varying in what effect that move has in addition to moving `HEAD`.

Comment: So, it sounds like "checkout" does mean something completely different (as compared to TFS anyway -- the TFS equivalent would be "getting" a particular "changeset").  Glad I looked this up! -- is there any magic constant for "latest"? (in TFS it's "T") -- that way we can just download the latest version of the code without knowing the "HEAD" label?

Comment: If you're on a branch, the branch name is the latest commit for that branch -- if you're not on a branch, you are on the latest commit.  I would use the log command to find the most recent commit in the repository without regard to branch and then manually move to it -- but I'm sure it can be automated if needed.

Comment: About the last paragraph: please note that `git checkout <commit> <path>` does not switch branches.

Comment: Your explanation isn't wrong but you forgot a very important (and potentially dangerous) use case : `git checkout <path>`.

Answer (score 38):

Let me explain some use cases of checkout with file, folder and branches so that it might be helpful in understanding.

Let say we have folder named `dev` and `index.html` also Everything is tracked and working directory is clean.

If I accidentally change file name `index.html` and I want to undo that i will simply use `git checkout index.html` it will recover that file state from repository currently selected branch.

Now if I made some change in `dev` folder and want to recover that. I can use `git checkout dev` but what if there is already branch named `dev` instead of checking out that folder it will pull down that branch. To avoid that I would rather do `git checkout -- dev`.

Now here bare double dash stands for current branch and asking git for folder `dev` from currently selected branch.

Similarly If I do `git checkout alpha dev` it will pull down dev folder from alpha branch.

This answer is for your first question 'git checkout really mean'.

Comment: In your last line _This answer is for your first question 'git checkout really mean'._  are you  checking out 'really' folder from 'mean' branch :P

Comment: shouldn't that be `really` branch and `mean` folder?

Answer (score 34):

"To check out" means that you take any given commit from the repository and re-create the state of the associated file and directory tree in the working directory.

When you check out a commit that is *not* a branch head (e.g. `git checkout HEAD~2`), you are on a so-called *detached* head. You can create commits here, but once you switch to a different branch, those commits will not be recoverable by a branch name and might even get removed by the garbage collector after some time.