# git checkout takes too long "Checking out submodules"

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

Every time i do a "git checkout ", it takes at least 90 secs to switch to a branch. It used to take less than a second. I see the message "Checking out submodules" and it takes a while to get out of that. How do I fix this please ?
Any help appreciated.

Tried re-installing git. But no change.

Comment: Show us your repositories. Without them there is too little information to help. Perhaps one or few of the submodules slowing down the process. Try to experiment with `git checkout --no-recurse-submodules`. Try to checkout in your submodules manually to see which one is the culprit.

Comment: Please visit these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957237/how-to-make-git-clone-faster-with-multiple-threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823520/git-checkout-to-a-branch-takes-long-time

Comment: @phd how do i see the submodules that are slowing down the process ?

Comment: I said "manually". Also `git submodule foreach` prints "Entering <submodule path>".

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the latest version of Git is faster (as in git 2.23). I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451807/6309) for instance progress on that front.

Then, as a workaround, check if `git checkout --no-recurse-submodules`  is quicker