# What does "git checkout" do if no argument is provided?

Tags: git

I accidentally typed `git checkout` in GIT CMD without any arguments in my working branch. The parent branch name is development.
After I hit the command it showed the following:

```
M       analytics-engine/build.gradle
M       analytics-engine/src/main/groovy/com/oracle/emcsas/securityanalytics/stats/timebucket/ExternalizeTimeBucket.java
M       analytics-engine/src/main/groovy/com/oracle/emcsas/securityanalytics/stats/timebucket/TimeBucket.java
```

But I did not notice any changes in my local branch. All the changes are there. So what did it actually do.

**git version 2.15.0.windows.1**

Comment: A different but related question is this: What did you *want* it to do? Why did you execute it? Only to learn git? Or did you execute it in the hopes that it did something specific?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)? It is explained there: *"You could omit <branch>, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the current branch", which is a glorified no-op with rather expensive side-effects to show only the tracking information, if exists, for the current branch."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do git checkouts really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296473/what-do-git-checkouts-really-mean)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The documentation says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt)

> ***git checkout* <branch>**
>
> ...
>
> You could omit <branch>, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the current branch", which is a glorified no-op with rather expensive side-effects to show only the tracking information, if exists, for the current branch

Comment: what does it mean exactly by saying "with rather expensive side-effects" ?

Answer (score 14):

It shows you the current modified and not commited files in your current branch

Comment: If there is a tracking branch it equals `git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>`

Comment: @evolutionxbox - No, it doesn't, as is obvious if you try to explain what `<branch>` is in your supposedly-equivalent command, while remembering that the question is what happens when you don't supply a branch name.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I'm getting this information from the git docs. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt - _"If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to [...]"_

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Ok.  So in your estimation, what is `<branch>` set to in the equivalent command, if I say `git checkout` with no further arguments?

Comment: Hmmm. Good point, I think I've read that part of the docs and assuming it's used when branch isn't there. It's not, only if the remote exists.

Comment: I also noticed that. It just summarizes the changes in your working dir (modified files are marked with 'M', deleted files with 'D', untracked files are not mentioned). But I couldnt any reference to this behavior in documentation.